# Whats the time complexity of finding a max recursively

Tags: time-complexity

I just wanted to make sure I'm going in the right direction. I want to find a max value of an array by recursively splitting it and find the max of each separate array. Because I am splitting it, it would be 2*T(n/2). And because I have to make a comparison at the end for the 2 arrays, I have T(1).
So would my recurrence relation be like this:

> T = { 2*T(n/2) + 1, when n>=2 ;T(1), when n = 1;

and and therefore my complexity would be Theta(nlgn)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula you composed seems about right, but your analysis isn't perfect.

```
T = 2*T(n/2) + 1 = 2*(2*T(n/4) + 1) + 1 = ...
```

For the i-th iteration you'll get:

```
Ti(n) = 2^i*T(n/2^i) + i
```

now what you want to know for which i does n/2^i equals 1 (or just about any constant, if you like) so you reach the end-condition of n=1. 
That would be the solution to n/2^I = 1 -> I = Log2(n). Plant it in the equation for Ti and you get:

```
TI(n) = 2^log2(n)*T(n/2^log2(n)) + log2(n) = n*1+log2(n) = n + log2(n)
```

and you get T(n) = O(n + log2(n) (just like @bdares said) = O(n) (just like @bdares said)

Comment: Is it normal to write O(n + log(n))? Seems like O(n) would suffice, in *every* event. In fact, why soft-ball it in like that? I feel like writing O(n + log(n)), while not wrong, is silly. We don't write O(n^2 + n) for Bubblesort. Am I missing something? If you're just using that for illustrative purposes, OK; I guess it's a little weird for me not to see the final step carried out... so if that's the case, just take this as a criticism of the style, not the content.

Comment: @bdares You're right. I should've added the last step. I avoid skipping the (n + log(n)) part when I explain this to avoid confusion, but I should make sure to add the last part as well.

Answer (score 2):

No, no... you are taking O(1) time for each recursion.

How many are there?

There are N leaves, so you know it's at least O(N).

How many do you need to compare to find the absolute maximum?  That's O(log(N)).

Add them together, don't multiply.  O(N+log(N)) is your time complexity.

Comment: oh i see. i was kind of confused because it looked similar to merge sort. so is recurrence relation right or wrong also?

Comment: Eh.. I'm really fuzzy on that, but it looks right.  Each level will add 1, then 2, then 4, then 8, and so on ... so I was wrong.  It will take 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + ... + 2^log(n) time for each step, and will therefore take O(2*n) time, which is O(n) time.  Incidentally the same as O(N+log(N)) which is also O(n), but the first explanation was wrong.